# Add a generic handler for Send and Publish methods of the MediatR library in asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

I use the CQS pattern in my asp.net core project. Let's start with an example to better explain what I want to achieve. I created a command:

```
public class EmptyCommand : INotification{}
```

The command handler:

```
public class EmptyCommandHandler : INotificationHandler<EmptyCommand>
{
    public Task Handle(EmptyCommand notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

The query:

```
public class EmptyQuery : IRequest<string>{}
```

The query handler:

```
public class EmptyQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<EmptyQuery, string>
{
    public Task<string> Handle(EmptyQuery notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

and this is a simple example of how to run the command and query and invoke the Handle method from the EmptyCommandHandler and EmptyQueryHandler:

```
readonly IMediator _mediator;

public HomeController(IMediator mediator)
{
    _mediator = mediator;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await _mediator.Publish(new EmptyCommand());
    var queryResult = await _mediator.Send(new EmptyQuery());   
    return View();  
}
```

Please bear in mind that query can return other types not necessarily the `string`.
I would like to create some kind of a bridge class e.g. `MediatorBoostrapper`, which allows me to run some business logic(e.g. log command/query via Logger) every time the Publish method is invoked and then
invoke the `public Task Handle(EmptyCommand notification,...` method from the command handler. The solution must be generic, so this method would be invoked every time I run the `Publish` method. I also want to be able to do the same thing for the `Send` method.

I was thinking about the creation of the `public class MediatorBoostrapper : IMediator`
but not sure what should be a proper implementation of the class and if my idea is good.
Any ideas? Cheers

**Edit**

1. I want to have an example of how to use the [Behaviors](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors)
   to create a generic way to run some external method from the generic handler every time I Run the `Send` method for queries. I want to have a similar example for `Publish` method, which I use for sending commands.
2. I want to have an example of how to use [Polymorphic dispatch](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#polymorphic-dispatch)
   for the creation of the GenericCommandHandler and a GenericQueryHandler

I created a sample project on GitHub which can be found [here](https://github.com/demos666/mediatr-generic-handler)
You can feel free to try to extend this project with your solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do in that class? Remember what the S in CQS stands for: Separation. Don't wrap up logic in every call that should be a separate logic. If it's simple enough, just add it to your Handler. Or extend the class, but it really depends a lot on what it is that it needs to do.

Comment: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors

Comment: I want to create some kind of middleware so I can log each command and query using the logger

Comment: In this case, I want to respect the DRY rule.

Comment: Peter this is pretty interesting, need to play with this approach and see what i can achieve

Comment: Behaviours won't work for Publish because they don't wrap INotificationHandlers.
Out of curiosity why are you using INotificationHandlers for handling Commands? An IRequestHandler doesn't have to send a response and can be used for the strict Command pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This time I want to answer the question starting from the end.

**2.**

> TL;DR Polymorphic Dispatch cannot be used for the CQS

After some time of playing with the MediatR library, reading the comments under my Question and consultation with my friend, I found the *Polymorphic Dispatch(PD)* can be used to create a generic handler only in case of the Commands. The PD solution cannot be implemented for Queries. Based on the [Documentation](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#polymorphic-dispatch), the handlers are **contravariant** and not covariant. This means the PD works **only** in the case where the `TResponse` is a constant type. In case of the Queries, this is false and each Query handler can return a different result.

I also found [this issue](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/24). I think it's interesting to know you can use the Polymorphic Dispatch only if your container supports it.

**1.** [Behaviors](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors) is the one and only solution for CQS when using the MediatR. 
Based on the comment under my question from #Steve and [comment from jbogard](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/274#issuecomment-394716576) I've found the way how to use Behaviors and IRequestHandler for the strict Command pattern. The full comment:

> Just to summarize the changes, there are 2 main flavors of requests:
>   those that return a value, and those that do not. The ones that do not
>   now implement `IRequest<T>` where `T : Unit`. This was to unify requests
>   and handlers into one single type. The diverging types broke the
>   pipeline for many containers, the unification means you can use
>   pipelines for any kind of request.
>
> It forced me to add the Unit type in all cases, so I've added some helper classes for you.
>
> - `IRequestHandler<T>` - implement this and you will return `Task<Unit>`.
> - `AsyncRequestHandler<T>` - inherit this and you will return `Task`.
> - `RequestHandler<T>` - inherit this and you will return nothing `(void)`.
>
> For requests that do return values:
>
> - `IRequestHandler<T, U>` - you will return `Task<U>`
> - `RequestHandler<T, U>` - you will return `U`
>
> I got rid of the AsyncRequestHandler because it really wasn't doing anything after the consolidation, a redundant base class.

**The example**

a) The Commands management:

```
public class EmptyCommand : IRequest{...}

public class EmptyCommandHandler : RequestHandler<EmptyCommand>
{
    protected override void Handle(EmptyCommand request){...}
}
```

b) The Queries management:

```
// can be any other type not necessarily `string`
public class EmptyQuery : IRequest<string>{...}

public class EmptyQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<EmptyQuery, string>
{
    public Task<string> Handle(EmptyQuery notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Sample response");
    }
}
```

c) The sample `LogginBehavior` class:

```
public class LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    readonly ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;

    public LoggingBehavior(ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var requestType = typeof(TRequest).Name;
        var response = await next();

        if (requestType.EndsWith("Command"))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Command Request: {request}");
        }
        else if (requestType.EndsWith("Query"))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Query Request: {request}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Query Response: {response}");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The request is not the Command or Query type");
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

d) To register the `LoggingBehavior` add the command

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
```

to the body of the `ConfigureServices` method in the Startup.cs.

e) The example of how to run sample command and query:

```
await _mediator.Send(new EmptyCommand());
var result = await _mediator.Send(new EmptyQuery());
```

Answer (score 6):

MediatR supports dispatching notifications to generic handlers ([polymorphic dispatch](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#polymorphic-dispatch)). For example:

```
public class GenericHandler<TNotification> : INotificationHandler<TNotification> 
    where TNotification : INotification
{
    public Task Handle(TNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This handler will be invoked for every notification that is published through `Publish()`. The same is true for requests (queries/commands). You should also take a look at [behaviors](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors).

If you're using MediatR with ASP.NET Core I suggest you use the [MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) library which takes care of wiring all the handlers together.

Comment: after i added `GenericHandler` to my project and tried to run the solution I received the error: `Cannot instantiate implementation type 'HighElo.Domain.CommandHandlers.GenericHandler` do i need to add some extra configuration to the Startup.cs?

Comment: @GoldenAge take look at this library: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection. It handles the registration of request handlers.

Comment: I'm already using this library. I tried to register the `GenericHandler` using many different approaches e.g. `services.AddMediatR(typeof(GenericHandler<EmptyCommand>));` and it still throws the same error. Not sure how should i register it..

Comment: You should only have to call `services.AddMediatR()` and it will wire all the requests and their handlers together.

Comment: So, I created a totally separate solution to test your idea, i uploaded it to GitHub and it works. When I added the same code to my project that I'm working on right now i receive this weird error that i mentioned before. You can find the example here: https://github.com/demos666/mediatr-generic-handler In my case I added `services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup),typeof(EmptyClass));` to the Startup.cs, to make it work because I store the commands and queries in a separate project.  I also need an implementation of the `GenericQueryHandler`.

Comment: In my project I have the same structure of project. The StartUp project is the .Web one. The .Domain project is linked to the .Web guy.

Comment: It blows at the very beginning, in the `public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }` after i run the solution in the debug mode, im getting the:`System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'HighElo.Domain.CommandHandlers.GenericCommandHandler1[TNotification]' for service type 'MediatR.INotificationHandler1[TNotification]'.' `

Comment: @GoldenAge did you try using `services.AddMediatR()` without explicitly specifying the assemblies? By default it will scan all the assemblies.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/henkmollema/fa4ef9a15167b8aad6aa09028f849cd1) for reference.

Comment: yes I tried, it works only in case if you store everything in one project

Comment: MediatR upgrade from version 5.1.0 to 6.0.0 solved above issue.